# Netbeans not displaying UI

Tags: user-interface

I'm running this in netbeans and it's not displaying anything. Does anyone know why netbeans isn't displaying the User Interface? Is it because I'm using an empty java file? My Code is below. I am new to netbeans and java so any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class UserInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public UserInterface() {
    setTitle("My First UI");
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(10,10,400,600);
    Container con = getContentPane();

    JLabel lblCustomerName = new JLabel("Customer Name");
    JTextField txtCustomerName = new JTextField();
    JButton btnOkay =  new JButton("Okay");

    lblCustomerName.setBounds(20,20,100,20);
    txtCustomerName.setBounds(125,20,100,20);
    btnOkay.setBounds(20,300,80,60);

    con.add(lblCustomerName);
    con.add(txtCustomerName);
    con.add(btnOkay);
    con.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new UserInterface();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java code cannot show your frame.

Please set in your Tester.class:

```
class Tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
      ui.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

And you could remove `con.setVisible(true);` from your UserInterface.class.

Comment: Thanks heaps! The above code worked when I ran it using cmd. So I wasn't sure why it didn't work in netbeans but cheers!